# Overlapping two video elements

Tags: html, video

I'm using the html5 video tag and div tag to hide and unhide elements to make two seperate video files appear to play together as if they were concatenated. The only thing is, I dont' know how to position two video elements at the same location. In fact, I don't know how to position elements anywhere besides the default location they end up at based on precedence. Essentially I hide and unhide elements to make this process work. Any hints on how to get positioning to work?

```
     function play(first, second){
        var video1 = document.getElementById("video1")
        var v1Hide = document.getElementById("v1")

        var video2 = document.getElementById("video2")
        var v2Hide = document.getElementById("v2")

        video1.setAttribute("src", first)
        video2.setAttribute("src", second)
        video1.load()
        video2.load()

        video1.play() //starts playing this one Visibly while 2nd is loaded but hidden

        setTimeout(function(){
          v1.style.visibility = 'hidden' 
          v2.style.visibility = 'visible'
          video2.play()
          video1.pause()
          }, 2000)
      }
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to read up on CSS positioning. For example: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/. In your case, it sounds like `position: absolute` should do the trick.

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! Also, the link is very helpful, that's the kind of stuff I'm always looking for. I hate it when someone just sends me a shitty example or snippet of code. I like being able to read through and really understand how the process works.